# Extracting table from html into htmltable in asp.net vb (htmlagilitypack)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-scraping, html-table, html-agility-pack

I am trying to grab a html table from a remote page and display the contents of this table in a htmltable on my site. I am using htmlagility pack. So far here is my code:

```
Imports HtmlAgilityPack
Partial Class ContentGrabExperiment
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'fetch the remote html page
        Dim web As New HtmlWeb()
        Dim html As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument = web.Load("http://www.thesite.com/page.html")

        'Create table
        Dim outputTable As New HtmlTable
        Dim tableRow As New HtmlTableRow
        Dim tableCell As New HtmlTableCell


        'Target the <table> tag 
        For Each table As HtmlNode In html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table")
            'Target the <tr> tags within the table
            For Each row As HtmlNode In table.SelectNodes("//tr")
                'Target the <td> tags within the <tr> tags
                For Each cell As HtmlNode In row.SelectNodes("//td")
                    'Set the value to that of the <td>
                    tableCell.InnerText = cell.InnerHtml
                    'Add the cell to the row
                    tableRow.Cells.Add(tableCell)
                Next
                'Add row to the outputTable 
                outputTable.Rows.Add(tableRow)
            Next
        Next
        'Add the table to the page
        PlaceHolderTable.Controls.Add(outputTable)
    End Sub
End Class
```

From this I was expecting to get the full table with innertext from the page, as a htmltable which I can then manipulate. What I get out of this code is:

```
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td>&amp;nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Please can someone point out where I am going wrong with my syntax. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

1) You only have one TableRow and one TableCell. You will need to create a new one for each row/cell. You can re-use the variables but you will need to "New" an object into them.

2) You might need to select `./tr` and `./td` to get only rows and cells in the current table / row.